# Trouble with compiling and running Java program using an external .jar library

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I've been trying to compile a single java class using another class from a .jar file, on the command line, but I keep running into a 'file not found error'. My file structure looks like this:

```
roguelike\
   |
   ---> asciiPanel.jar
   ---> src\
         |
         ---> rltut\
                |
                ----> ApplicationMain.java
```

And in ApplicationMain.java I have at the top line:

```
package rltut;
```

I looked at the wiki for the java classpath argument, and it told me I need to include the path for the jar too, so I'm using this command in the terminal (bash on MacOSX)

```
$ javac -cp ~/Documents/dev/java/roguelike/src:~/Documents/dev/java/roguelike/asciiPanel.jar rltut.ApplicationMain.java
-- Output --
error: file not found: rltut.ApplicationMain.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

And note that I'm executing from the roguelike directory, I've tried executing the command from outside this directory or in src but nothing has worked. If someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it, I'm quite new to java and most of the articles I've read on classpath haven't really made sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you want `src/rltut/ApplicationMain.java` at the end of the command line, not `rltut.ApplicationMain.java`. This isn't really to do with the jar file - you're just not specifying the source file properly.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the compiler is finding the .java file now. However, I'm getting an error saying the asciiPanel package can not be found (the one in the .jar). I have this line in the .java file: 'import asciiPanel.AsciiPanel'. Do I need to specify a full address here too?

Comment: No, you should only need to specify the type name. Without knowing more about the jar file, it's hard to know what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, this seems really bizarre to me. I removed "~/Documents/dev/java/roguelike/src:" from the classpath, and all of a sudden it compiles. Great, but when I now try and run "java -cp ~/Documents/dev/java/roguelike/asciiPanel.jar src/rltut/ApplicationMain", I get "Error: Could not find or load main class src.rltut.ApplicationMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.rltut.ApplicationMain". I'm really sorry to keep bothering you, but this is making absolutely 0 sense to me.

Comment: Well now when you're running, you're not including the code that you've just built - and you've specified the main class incorrectly too. You need to include wherever you're building the classes in the classpath when running (along with the jar file), and run `rltut.ApplicationMain` as that class is your entry point.

Comment: So I've run "java -cp ~/Documents/dev/java/roguelike/asciiPanel.jar:~/Documents/dev/java/roguelike/src 
   src/rltut/ApplicationMain", pretty much just added the path to the source files back to the class path, but I'm still getting a class not found exception for ApplicationMain. Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know, but at this point you're effectively using Stack Overflow as an interactive debugging tool, and that's not the way the site is meant to be used. Additionally, you don't seem to have taken on my point that you're specifying the main class incorrectly - see my previous comment. This will be my last comment on this question; someone else may choose to chat, but I don't have time I'm afraid, and I don't think it further the site's aims. (You do have my sympathies, but it's just not the way this site works. You may be better off finding someone in the real world to pair with.)

Comment: Fair enough man, apologies if I've wasted your time and I know this is really not how you're meant to use SO but this is causing me a lot more trouble than I usually have w/ stuff like this. Thanks again for your help and I'll try what you've suggested, I do appreciate it.